# WPF moduls / plugins in own AppDomain - framework support?

Tags: wpf, prism, mvvm-light, prism-4

I need to write an application which can load plugins. I read the PRISM 4 documentation and i like the "Region" concept of the framework. But all modules are loaded in the first AppDomain - but i need to build an application where 3rd party plugins can crash without crashing the whole app (so i think multiple app domains are the best solution?)

Has anybody some experience with that topic? Should i build it on top of MVVM light myself? Is PRISM 4 the tool I'm looking for?

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, none of the popular MVVM frameworks (Prism, Caliburn, Calcium etc.) support cross-appdomain module lifecycle and, just as importantly, cross-appdomain messaging out of the box. This said, it's not impossible to customise any of them to:

- allow for modules to be loaded in different appdomains, perhaps based
  on some configuration option;
- create a remoting proxy for their messaging components (eg. event aggregator in Prism) so that a message is serialised into a different appdomain.

For one, Prism4 allows for multiple extensibility points on its bootstrapper, module catalog and service locator components, so loading DLLs and initalising their entry points on different appdomain is not too hard. Creating a remoting proxy of the event aggregator is a bit more complex.

I have personally resorted to creating a different message broker that works cross-process as well as within the same appdomain, however I had to write it from scratch.

Comment: Did you use IPC as message protocol? Is it hard to use WPF and MAF?

Comment: I used Memory Mapped Files for inter-process. You need a bit more coding to synchronise read/write access and maintain a dedicated memory area to store the index of the last byte written (4 or 8 bytes).

Comment: Using WPF and MEF: not too hard. Both Prism and Caliburn offer integration with MEF. [MEFContrib](http://mefcontrib.codeplex.com/) is a prominent effort. Google "Caliburn Micro MEF" to get similar projects on Caliburn.